# How to Parse Data into Unique Columns in CSV File

Tags: perl, csv, awk

So, I have a csv file with thousands of columns. As an example, let say I have the first column as a server name and the remaining columns as ports that are open.

eg:

```
SERVER1,22,25,110,3389,etc
SERVER2,22,110,3389,45001,etc
SERVER3,3389,45001,etc
```

I am trying to find a way with any command line tools to process this into unique columns such that the above would become:

```
SERVER1,22,25,110,3389,,etc
SERVER2,22,,110,3389,45001,etc
SERVER3,,,,3389,45001,etc
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: And what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perl

```
perl -MSet::Scalar -e '
    $ports = Set::Scalar->new;
    open $fh, "<", shift @ARGV;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        @fields = split /,/;
        $ports->insert(@fields[1..$#fields]);
    }
    @all_ports = sort {$a <=> $b} $ports->members;
    seek $fh, 0, 0;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        @fields = split /,/;
        print $fields[0];
        $ports = Set::Scalar->new(@fields[1..$#fields]);
        print(",", ($ports->has($_) ? $_ : "")) for @all_ports;
        print "\n"
    }
' file.csv
```

```
SERVER1,etc,22,25,110,3389,
SERVER2,etc,22,,110,3389,45001
SERVER3,etc,,,,3389,45001
```

Don't worry about "etc" showing up first: the ports are sorted numerically and the string "etc" is treated as the number zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
  a[$i];
  next
}
{
  i=2;
  b=$1;
  for(j in a)
  {
    if($i == j)
    {
      b=b FS $i;
      i++
    }
    else
      b=b FS
  }
  print b
}
' infile infile
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong in that logic since you're only incrementing `i` when `$i == j` so it won't necessarily test all of the fields. Try it...

Comment: It's ok with the given data because ports number are in ordinal order. If a line look like that SERVER2,22,7885,110,3389,45001 , you are right, it's false.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}
NR==FNR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        allVals[$i]
    }
    next
}
{
    delete curVals
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        curVals[$i]
    }
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i in allVals) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, (i in curVals ? i : "")
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
SERVER1,etc,22,25,110,3389,
SERVER2,etc,22,,110,3389,45001
SERVER3,etc,,,,3389,45001
```